# Popen in multiprocessing.Pool is extremely slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing, popen

I'm trying to run multiple ngspice simulation in parallel. So I have a function `_runNgspice` that executes ngspice.

```
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

```
def _runNgspice(param):
    runDir=param['runDir']
    spiceFile=param['spiceFile']
    logfile= os.path.join(runDir, 'run.log')
    with open(logfile, 'wb') as nglog:
       ngcommand=['ngspice', '-b', f'{spiceFile}']
       with Popen(ngcommand, shell=False, cwd=runDir, stdout=PIPE) as proc:
            nglog.write(proc.stdout.read())
    result=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(runDir, 'result.csv'))
    return result
```

To run multiple instances of `_runNgspice` in parallel, I do the following:

```
p=Pool(processes=processes)
with p as pool:
    result=pool.map(_runNgspice, param)
```

This code works very well on my laptop (CPU: i7-1165G7, Linux kernel 5.15, python 3.9.7). However on my desktop system (CPU: i7-12700, Linux kernel 5.17, python 3.9.7) this is extremely slow. What I find interesting: if I run `_runNgspice` without `pool.map` all is fine. As soon as it is executed via `pool.map` it gets extremely slow. Also interesting: If I execute `time python3 investigate.py` I get a result like this:

```
real    0m21,267s
user    0m1,271s
sys     0m2,931s
```

There is almost no user time. Any ideas what could be the cause for the issue I'm observing?

Comment: Why would you use multiprocessing for this? It's pure overhead and adds no value at all over just spawning a separate `Popen` object from a single thread -- but it makes you transfer the params and results across processes, so they need to be serialized and deserialized.

Comment: (Also, knowing if you get the same slowdown with all the Popen objects launched from the same thread would do a lot of good in terms of narrowing down where your performance issue could be coming from, as it would rule out the aforementioned serialization/deserialization overhead).

Comment: As a general rule: Use multiprocessing _only_ when you're doing work _that needs to hold the Python GIL_ across multiple processes in parallel; and when the amounts of data you need to move in and out of your pool entries is low enough that the transfer overhead is tolerable. The GIL is _always_ released while waiting for a separate process to run (or waiting on blocking I/O reads), so you get none of multiprocessing's advantages and all of its disadvantages.

Comment: Try switching to `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` as a drop in replacement for the regular pool. It has lower overhead using threads, and you don't especially need separate processes in this case anyway (as mentioned by @CharlesDuffy)

Comment: The reason for using multiprocessing instead of simply using Popen is that I'd like to parallelize reading back the results. The shown code is a simplified example to explain the issue. In the full featured version ngspice creates thousands of .csv files which need to be parsed.

Comment: Using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool` does not solve the issue. I've also tried using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. The issue is still there.

Comment: @user1380653 It would seem then it's not really python that's slow here then, but rather your spice simulation has some sort of problem running multiple instances at once on your desktop. As a side note, I'd try pushing the `pd.read_csv(` call back to the main process. It's probably faster to do that all in the same process without serializing / deserializing. (also FYI, `dummy.Pool` is exactly the same thing as `pool.ThreadPool`)

Comment: It turns out, the cause is not multiprocessing. Running parallel instances of ngspice using `Popen` alone is still causing the same issue. The issue is also not ngspice. If I start 2 instances in 2 terminals simulations run fast. So the issue seems to stem form `Popen`.

Comment: Using `os.system`instead of `Popen` and relying on `multiprocessing.Pool` for parallelization still shows the same behavior as `Popen` alone. It must be related to the system.

Comment: When you test "2 instances in 2 terminals", is that _on the same system where your Python code runs_?

Comment: Yes 2 instances 2 terminal is on that same system.